# return a message box if cell in column C contains the word "FALSE" or "ERROR"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro which send a message through a message box if any cell of my column C contain the word “ERROR” or “FALSE”… I would like to extend this macro in order that it returns this message box if any cell of my column C contains the word “ERROR” or “FALSE” in a string (I want to do that because sometimes I can have some spaces like for example "ERROR " or " FALSE") … Please find the code of my macro below.
Many Thanks in advance for your help.
Xavi

```
Sub reporterroroncolumnB ()
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim X As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For X = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(X, 3) = "ERROR" Or Cells(X, 3) = "FALSE" Then
            MsgBox "Cell in column C should be reviewed"
        End If
    Next X
End Sub
```

Comment: Showing a messagebox in a loop till the last row is a very bad idea... I would recommend looping and storing the cell address in a string and then in the end just showing 1 messagebox with the cell addresses

Comment: Alternatively you could use `.Find` and `.FindNext` with `xlPart` to achieve what you want :) Much faster than looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Instr(Ucase(Cells(X, 3)),"ERROR") + instr(Ucase(Cells(X, 3)),"FALSE") > 0 then
```